# i Installed Ubuntu 17.10 alongside windows 10 But Windows 10 starts Automatically without showing OS Selection message

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

-> i installed ubuntu alongside windows10 
-> both are installed in UEFI mode 
-> but it automatically start windows10 
-> i have separate partition Named as EFI  which contain 
    EFI\Boot\ 
    EFI\Microsoft\Boot 
    EFI\ubuntu(some Files)
    [EFI\ubuntu(Files list)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDXvX.jpg)

when i want to start UBUNTU at that time i have to press NOVO(Special Button On Lenovo Laptop for Go in Bios Or Select Boot option) button and select ubuntu

but it is not convenient way because novo button is pressed by only tiny pin

so anyone have any solution which is show me GRUB or bootselection at that time of starting my laptop

thanks in advance

Comment: does the firmware boot order settings allow you to select OS to boot? If it, does switch from Windows to Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try installing [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

This will help you to recover the properly boot systems from other operative systems.

First, install the repositories

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

Then, update them

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Later, install the program

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then, a screen like this will appear:

[image]

Use the recommended repair, or take a look the the Community help page of the program (linked above)

Answer (score 0):

As Commented above by *ravery* i just change boot order in UEFI setting and it first show me grub2.0 with windows and ubuntu option selection

thank you all of you to quick support